Cloudfront (CDN) with Internal Application Load Balancer
I have deployed my application in EKS Clusters inside the VPC (Private Cluster). Created one Internal ALB for my application. I need to access the Internal Application Load Balancer with cloudfront. Made configuration for Cloudfront. When I try to hit the cloudfront distribution URL it's not connecting to my Internal ALB.
Is there any way to connect the Internal ALB with Cloudfront?
Note: I dont have any SSL certificate to configure HTTPS, using only http.
Thanks in advance.

CloudFront can't access your internal load balancer, only resources in your VPC can access that load balancer. You have to make the load balancer public for CloudFront to access it.
If you want to secure the load balancer so that only CloudFront can access it, you can configure the inbound rule in the load balancer's security group to only allow the CloudFront managed prefix list.

If anyone comes here, this is such a good suggestion, it works for me. I made my ALB public but added the SG rule:
- IpProtocol: tcp
FromPort: 443
ToPort: 443
SourcePrefixListId:  pl-3b927c52  # Replace with CloudFront's managed prefix list ID for your region
